# Align HTML Layout

Tags: html, css

I need to build this Site [Mockup](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/mockup.html)

Here is what I have right now [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html)

When you scroll down to the bottom of the page you see that height of the Layout does not fit (there remains a black line on the bottom).

I tried some adjustments, but the height of the Layout is still wrong.

What can be done to fix it?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>RW-Fliesen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"     title="Logo"></a>
                <div class="contact-info" title="contact-    info"></div>
                <ul class="mn">
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn1 "></a>        </li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn2 "></a>    </li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn3 "></a>    </li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn4 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn5 "></a></li>
                    <li><a href=" " title="" class="mn6 "></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="top">
                    <div class="foto1" title="Fliesen">     <img src="foto1.png" alt="Fliesen1"/> </div>
                    <div class="foto2" title="Fliesen">     <img src="foto2.png" alt="Fliesen2"/> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="leftcolumn">
                    <div class="text" title="text">
                        <p> RW-Fliesen <br />
                            Ludwig-Thoma-Str. 36 <br />
                            82008 Unterhaching 
                        </p>
                        <div class="text2"     title="text">
                            <p> Telefon: <br />
                                Fax: <br />
                                Mobil: <br     />
                                Email: <br />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text3"     title="text">
                            <p> 089 - 358 557     88 <br />
                                089 - 358 557 89 <br />
                                0179 - 673 77 41 <br />
                                info@rw-fliesen.com <br />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text4" title="text">
                            <p> Betriebsnummer: 7084943 <br />    <span class="text-blue"> Eingetragen in die Handwerksrolle bei <br /> der Handwerkskammer     für München <br /> und Oberbayern. </span>   </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="face" title="face">
                        <iframe id="f580fdad4"     name="f83387924" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 690px; width: 262px;" class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=&amp;locale=de_DE&amp;sdk=joey&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Dfe1e61258%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.rw-fliesen.com%252Ff21318bbdc%26domain%3Dwww.rw-fliesen.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;height=290&amp;header=true&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=false&amp;width=262&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FRW-Fliesen%2F115860578491339&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="rightcolumn">
                    <div class="text5" title="text">
                        <p> Wir sind Ihr fachlich     kompetenter Fliesenleger- und Innenausbaubetrieb in Unterhaching.  </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body { background: #1c1b17 url(bg.jpg) repeat-x; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 1000px;     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;}

p {     color: #17142B; line-height: 18px;  padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-    weight: 600; }
h3 { color: #003d7a; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0px;     }    
h4 { color: #2f303f; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 20px; padding: 0px;     }       

.text-blue {     color: #003d7a; line-height: 16px; padding: 0; font-size: 10px;     font-weight: 600; }


#wrapper { width: 1000px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
#header { height: 400px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; }
#header .logo { position: absolute; width: 374px; height: 221px; display: block; float:         left; cursor: pointer; background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent; top: 55px;     left: 10px; }
#header .contact-info { position: absolute; width: 293px; height: 133px; display:     block; float: left; cursor: pointer; background: url(contact-info.png) 0 0 no-repeat     transparent; top: 100px; left: 700px; }

ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 978px; margin: 0; padding:     0; list-style-type: none; }
ul.mn li { float: left; }
ul.mn li a { display: block; float: left; height: 73px; }
ul.mn li a.mn1 { width: 104px; background-image: url('mn1.png'); background-position: 0     0; }
ul.mn li a.mn2 { width: 212px; background-image: url('mn2.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn3 { width: 142px; background-image: url('mn3.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn4 { width: 128px; background-image: url('mn4.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn5 { width: 117px; background-image: url('mn5.png'); }
ul.mn li a.mn6 { width: 147px; background-image: url('mn6.png'); }
ul.mn li a.active, ul.mn li a:hover { background-position: 0 73px; }

#content { height: 1000px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; }

#top { height: 300px; width: 1000px; display: block; position: relative; margin-bottom:     100px; }
#top .foto1 { width: 452px; height: 139px; float: left; margin-top: 30px; }
#top .foto2 { width: 253px; height: 138px; float: left; margin-top: 30px; margin-left:     100px; }

#leftcolumn { height: 800px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative; float:     left; }
#leftcolumn .text { height: 10px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative;     margin-bottom: 90px; }
#leftcolumn .text2 { height: 10px; width: 50px; display: inline-block; position:     relative; }
#leftcolumn .text3 { height: 10px; width: 200px; display: inline-block; position:     relative;  padding-left: 30px; }
#leftcolumn .text4 { height: 10px; width: 300px; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin-top: 80px; }
#leftcolumn .face { height: 100px; width: 300px; display: block; position: relative; margin-top: 290px; }

#rightcolumn { height: 800px; width: 700px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;     margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 0px; float: right; }
#rightcolumn  .text5 { height: 300px; width: 700px; display: inline-block; position:     relative; }

#footer
```

Comment: Hello, set body margin, in http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/mockup.html is 8px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an iframe with Facebook information in your page. This iframe extends to the bottom of the page and is causing the black background to be visible.

You need to lower the height of this iframe. Currently it's set like this (inline):

```
<iframe id="f580fdad4" name="f83387924" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 690px; width: 262px;" class="fb_ltr" src="..."></iframe>
```

If you change the height to maximum 684px the black bar dissapears:

```
<iframe id="f580fdad4" name="f83387924" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 684px; width: 262px;" class="fb_ltr" src="..."></iframe>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Please remind to accept / up vote the answer(s) that helped you.

Comment: Of course I accept it now. Would be nice if you could upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that your menu bar was not lining up within your header, I do not have 10 reputation points yet so I cannot share the image file of how your page look in my browser Chrome Version: 26.0.1410.63. If you would like that image please feel free to email me and I will send to you.

Making the assumption that you were trying to mimic the mock-up site that you referenced in your initial post. I believe you should make the following adjustments to section of your css code that addresses your menu bar. What you provided:

```
ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 978px; margin: 0; padding:0; list-style-type: none; }
```

What I am proposing:

```
ul.mn { position: absolute; float: left; top: 316px; width: 850px; margin: 0 auto 0 10px; padding:0; list-style-type: none;}
```

Notice that I changed the width to reflect the width as dictated by the combined widths of each of your defined button divs to 850px from 978px, then I proposed that instead of setting all of the margins to 0 that you make the top 0, the right auto, bottom 0, and the left 10px (because from what I perceive from your mock-up the left side of the menu is to line up with the left side of the logo).  Making those changes I was able to get your menu bar to sit nicely at the base of your header div.

Please keep, at least me, informed on your progress.  I am always looking to share ideas and learn how other approach problems.  I believe it makes us all that much more intelligent.

Best of luck,
Steve